# "string indices must be integers, not 'tuple'" during web scraping in Python

Tags: python, web, backend

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    newstr=(data1[m.start(),end])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'tuple'
```

I was doing web scraping.

Code:

```
m=re.search('<div class="read-more-content">',data1)
newstr=(data1[m.start(),(m.start()+401)])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    newstr=(data1[m.start(),(m.start()+401)])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'tuple'
end= m.start()+401
newstr=(data1[m.start(),end])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    newstr=(data1[m.start(),end])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'tuple'
```

Tried this but didn't worked.

Comment: You are trying to get characters at a position in a string by referring to those characters start and end position `data[m.start(), end]` where `m.start()` is likely returning a tuple of indices where a match was found from your regex. Do a `print(m.start())` and you'll likely find it's not a single number being returned. For multiple matches found in that match object, which one do you want? You likely need to specify or change your regex to be more targeted.

Comment: The error message says clearly what you did wrong: you passed a tuple (start, stop) as index.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, to get a slice of an array, you should use a colon to separate the start and the end of the section of the array you want to get.

In your case, the code becomes:

```
m = re.search('<div class="read-more-content">',data1)
newstr = (data1[m.start() : (m.start()+401)])
```